# I came accross internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have simple .htaccess. I use Open Server.  I came accross internal server error.

Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

**I don't understand where is a problem**

```
RewriteEngine On


# Rewrite for login.php
RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC, L]
```

Comment: Do you have anything with more detail in the error log? Is it all pages or just `login.php` you get this behavior for?

Comment: try it like this: `RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [NC, L]`

Comment: Error 500
snscld.sinus.uz
Apache

I simply use .htaccess for only login.php

Comment: I attempted like **RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [NC, L]**. However, this error occured again

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Also there is a white space in your flags `[NC, L]` if that's not a typo ,try removing the white space. Change  `NC, L` to `NC,L`

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: There is no any differences if I remove white space between NC, and L

Comment: Then perhaps there is something else that caused the server error. Check your server error log for info about the 500  error.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and ideas. I found it!!!